# Show that any algorithm that computes the following problem runs in $\Omega(n^2)$ time

Tags: combinatorics

The problem I'm working on says the following:

> Given an array *A*[1...*n*] of *n* integers, we would like to compute
>    a 2-dimensional array *B*[1...*n*][1...*n*], such that B[*i*][*j*] is
>    the sum of the integers *A*[*i*],...,*A*[*j*] whenever *i* $\le$ *j*.
>    If *i* $\gt$ *j*, then the value of *B*[*i*][*j*] can be any arbitrary
>    number. Show that any algorithm that computes *B*[1...*n*][1...*n*]
>    runs in $\Omega(n^2$) time.

I'm working under the assumption that any algorithm running on a 2-dimensional array is going to have to end up running $n^2$ times in the worst case scenario given what I know about coding. You go through 1...*n* once in the outer loop, and once again in the inner loop. The summation of *i* to *j* itself can likely be done in constant time, so the overall, worst-case run-time of the algorithm would be dependent on the two loops. Since the loop for *B* runs inside *A*, it is the product of their run-times: $\Omega(n)$ * $\Omega(n)$ = $\Omega(n^2)$.

Assuming my thought process is correct, how would I go about wording a "proof" for the above to show that no matter what else occurs in the algorithm, it will always run in $\Omega(n^2)$ time? Or have I missed the point entirely and the way the summation of *i* to *j* is done is important to the run-time?

Comment: the fact that $\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} i = O(n^2)$ gives the answer,even if the other values are given in just $O(1)$ step.

Comment: Why is this not trivial? If you are actually filling a two-dimensional array, you have to do $\Omega(1)$ work per array entry and you have $n^2$ array entries. Considering what work one might need to do to figure out what values should be stored in each cell is completely superfluous.

Comment: You have shown that there is an algorithm that runs in $\Omega(n^2)$ time.  You are being asked to prove that there is no other algorithm that runs faster.  A comparison would be sorting numbers.  You might describe straight insertion and prove it runs in $\Omega(n^2)$ but we know there are algorithms that run in $\Omega(n \log n)$

Comment: @Hurkyl That was my initial suspicion, but I fear I fell into the trap of over-complicating the problem. Thanks for reaffirming.

Comment: I thought it might be that; I had to ask though because sometimes the actual question is not the one posted -- e.g. an author might forget to mention that the problem is about counting the number of times `+` needs to be invoked, and ignoring other operations.